# Volume Displays "X" For my USB Drive in Computer Management

Tags: windows-10, usb, windows-explorer, storage, disk-management

When I plug my USB drive into my computer, It does not show up in explorer.

I've tried to follow tutorials on how to get it to show up, but I get stuck here:

[image]

The drive shows an X as volume and does not want to show up on the lists of disks where I can change the drive letter or change settings.

The drive did contain Information but It is being displayed as 100% Free storage.

Any way I can Access or at least format this drive to make it usable again?

Comment: Does it do this on any PC you connect it to? Is there data on the drive?

Comment: There is 1 file on this drive. It does not show up on other devices when you look at explorer.

Comment: What does it show in the lower section of disk management for that drive?

Comment: https://imgur.com/aGy2HTS - that specific drive does not show up at the bottom section of disk management.

Comment: Check device manager with the drive plugged in, any error for a usb device in there? If so what is the error?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UViEYM3 - I believe its the Unkown USB Device (Set Address Failed) - Says Error Code 43

Comment: Have you tried to install some Device Drivers using a Software Utility such as [_DriverToolkit_](http://www.drivertoolkit.com/) and retried to see if it is working after the newly installed Device Driver? Have you tried using the [`DiskPart`](file://C:/Windows/System32/DiskPart.Exe) Software Utility on it?

Comment: Looks like the usb device has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the USB Up in Device manager, checking for updates on windows updates and restarting the computer after updates were installed seemed to have fixed the USB on all devices and I was able to recover all the data.